# Ask user to enter word until they enter "exit"

Tags: java

> Ask user to enter word until they enter "exit", when they enter exit display all of their entered words without the "exit".

I'm confused how to combine all of their words and display it at the end, I know I will need another loop for that

```
import java.util.*;

public class testprac {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
      String word = input.nextLine();

      if (word.equals("exit")) {
        System.out.println("Exited");
        System.out.println("You entered: ");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try storing user input in a list or an array

Comment: You will need to store the input somewhere. Please show your attempts  at that

Comment: If you stored the words in something, a  list for example, could you print the elements of the list when the user exited?

Comment: "I know I will need another loop for that ... " -  That is one way to do it.  There are others.

Comment: but to store into an array, wouldn't I need to know how many strings they are going to enter?

Comment: You could use an ArrayList, which doesn't need to know the size when you make it.

Comment: @Boundz that's why you'll require `ArrayList` as mentioned above. Now you need to attempt on it.

Comment: Is there a way other than ArrayList? My course has not covered ArrayList yet but if that is the only way then I will take a stab at it :)

Comment: You could store the words in a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array or List to store the inputs  and then loop through the list or array to print.You can also to toString() method to print.

```
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Arrays;
     import java.util.List;
     import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Temp {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
        String word = input.nextLine();

        if (word.equals("exit")) {
            System.out.println("Exited");
            System.out.println("You entered: "+inputs);
            break;
        } else {

            inputs.add(word);
        }

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import java.util.*;
public class testprac {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a word:");
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (inputScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputScanner.nextLine();          
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);        
        while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
            String s = lineScanner.nextLine();
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                System.out.println("Exited");
                System.out.println("You entered: ");
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                lineScanner.close();
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                sb.append(s);
            }
         }
     }
     inputScanner.close();
  }
```